# Where are the gains using numba coming from for pure numpy code?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I would like to understand where the gains are coming from when using Numba to accelerate pure `numpy` code in a for loop. Are there any profiling tools that allow you to look into `jitted` functions?

The demo code (as below) is just using very basic matrix multiplication to provide work to the computer. Are the observed gains from:

1. a faster `loop`,
2. the recasting of `numpy` functions intercepted by the `jit` during the compilation process, or
3. less overhead with `jit` as numpy outsources execution via wrapper functions to low level libraries such as `LINPACK`

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import pandas as pd

#Dimensions of Matrices
i = 100 
j = 100

def pure_python(N,i,j):
    for n in range(N):
        a = np.random.rand(i,j)
        b = np.random.rand(i,j)
        c = np.dot(a,b)

@jit(nopython=True)
def jit_python(N,i,j):
    for n in range(N):
        a = np.random.rand(i,j)
        b = np.random.rand(i,j)
        c = np.dot(a,b)

time_python = []
time_jit = []
N = [1,10,100,500,1000,2000]
for n in N:
    time = %timeit -oq pure_python(n,i,j)
    time_python.append(time.average)
    time = %timeit -oq jit_python(n,i,j)
    time_jit.append(time.average)

df = pd.DataFrame({'pure_python' : time_python, 'jit_python' : time_jit}, index=N)
df.index.name = 'Iterations'
df[["pure_python", "jit_python"]].plot()
```

produces the following chart.

[image: runtime comparisons for a range of iteration lengths]

Comment: I think Numba recognizes `np.random.rand` and `np.dot`. (If it didn't, I don't think it'd let you use them in nopython mode.)

Comment: Indeed. They are supported by ``numba`` as per the docs. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html. I am mainly curious about how the code interception works and if that is the source of gains in the above example.

Comment: Could you add some setup info?  On Win 64, python 3.5, numba 0.33, I have only a modest speedup (10-15%)

Comment: Sure. I am on Linux Mint 18, Linux Kernel 4.4.0-45-generic, python 3.5, numba 0.30.1, Intel Xeon CPU E5-1620 @ 3.6Ghz x 4

Comment: The answer as far as i know is both 1) and 2).  `numba` compiles the function as `c` code.  As such, it speeds up the loop  parsing significantly, and speeds up `numpy` functions with significant `python` overhead (usually by stripping that overhead and forcing explicit data ordering - i.e. no `axis` keywords, no `einsum`, no `size` parameters on most constructors (`random.rand` being an exception) . . . All those things can be done explicitly in the now-faster `for` loops)

Comment: does anybody know if maybe the numba jit will reduce allocations? Like maybe the same allocated memory is being reused for each iteration?

Answer (score 7):

TL:DR The random and looping get accelerated, but the matrix multiply doesn't except for small matrix size. At small matrix/loop size, there seems to be significant speedups that are probably related to python overhead. At large N, the matrix multiply begins to dominate and the jit less helpful

Function definitions, using a square matrix for simplicity.

```
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import pandas as pd

#Dimensions of Matrices
N = 1000

def py_rand(i, j):
    a = np.random.rand(i, j)

jit_rand = jit(nopython=True)(py_rand)

def py_matmul(a, b):
    c = np.dot(a, b)

jit_matmul = jit(nopython=True)(py_matmul)

def py_loop(N, val):
    count = 0
    for i in range(N):
        count += val     


jit_loop = jit(nopython=True)(py_loop)      

def pure_python(N,i,j):
    for n in range(N):
        a = np.random.rand(i,j)
        b = np.random.rand(i,j)
        c = np.dot(a,a)

jit_func = jit(nopython=True)(pure_python)
```

Timing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Func', 'jit', 'N', 'Time'])
def meantime(f, *args, **kwargs):
    t = %timeit -oq -n5 f(*args, **kwargs)
    return t.average


for N in [10, 100, 1000, 2000]:
    a = np.random.randn(N, N)
    b = np.random.randn(N, N)

    df = df.append({'Func': 'jit_rand', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(jit_rand, N, N)}, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append({'Func': 'py_rand', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(py_rand, N, N)}, ignore_index=True)

    df = df.append({'Func': 'jit_matmul', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(jit_matmul, a, b)}, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append({'Func': 'py_matmul', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(py_matmul, a, b)}, ignore_index=True)

    df = df.append({'Func': 'jit_loop', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(jit_loop, N, 2.0)}, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append({'Func': 'py_loop', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(py_loop, N, 2.0)}, ignore_index=True)

    df = df.append({'Func': 'jit_func', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(jit_func, 5, N, N)}, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append({'Func': 'py_func', 'N': N, 'Time': meantime(pure_python, 5, N, N)}, ignore_index=True)

df['jit'] = df['Func'].str.contains('jit')
df['Func'] = df['Func'].apply(lambda s: s.split('_')[1])
df.set_index('Func')
display(df)
```

result:

```
    Func    jit     N   Time
0   rand    True    10  1.030686e-06
1   rand    False   10  1.115149e-05
2   matmul  True    10  2.250371e-06
3   matmul  False   10  2.199343e-06
4   loop    True    10  2.706000e-07
5   loop    False   10  7.274286e-07
6   func    True    10  1.217046e-05
7   func    False   10  2.495837e-05
8   rand    True    100 5.199217e-05
9   rand    False   100 8.149794e-05
10  matmul  True    100 7.848071e-05
11  matmul  False   100 2.130794e-05
12  loop    True    100 2.728571e-07
13  loop    False   100 3.003743e-06
14  func    True    100 6.739634e-04
15  func    False   100 1.146594e-03
16  rand    True    1000    5.644258e-03
17  rand    False   1000    8.012790e-03
18  matmul  True    1000    1.476098e-02
19  matmul  False   1000    1.613211e-02
20  loop    True    1000    2.846572e-07
21  loop    False   1000    3.539849e-05
22  func    True    1000    1.256926e-01
23  func    False   1000    1.581177e-01
24  rand    True    2000    2.061612e-02
25  rand    False   2000    3.204709e-02
26  matmul  True    2000    9.866484e-02
27  matmul  False   2000    1.007234e-01
28  loop    True    2000    3.011143e-07
29  loop    False   2000    7.477454e-05
30  func    True    2000    1.033560e+00
31  func    False   2000    1.199969e+00
```

It looks like numba is optimizing away the loop, so I'm not gonna bother including it in the compare

plot:

```
def jit_speedup(d):
    py_time = d[d['jit'] == False]['Time'].mean()
    jit_time = d[d['jit'] == True]['Time'].mean()
    return py_time / jit_time 

import seaborn as sns
result = df.groupby(['Func', 'N']).apply(jit_speedup).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Jit Speedup'})
result = result[result['Func'] != 'loop']
sns.factorplot(data=result, x='N', y='Jit Speedup', hue='Func')
```

[image]

So for the loop being 5 repetitions, the jit speeds things up quite solidly until the matrix multiply becomes expensive enough to make the other overhead insignificant in comparison.

Comment: You might be interested in repairing the `def py_loop():` code, as the original code turned out to be principally an **`O( 1 )`** scaled ( conceptually, perhaps an overlooked shortcut / masked variable error, independent on `N` ), which skews the experiment with returning always **just `~ 163 - 294 [ns]`** processing durations ( which confirms just "constant" plain call-signature processing overhead + a JMP / RET durations, not any `N`-times loop-ed code execution ).

Comment: No, **you have to return a value** - a "there"-produced value, otherwise the JIT-compiler analysis does not see any tangible reason for making the silicon loop so many times through a "silent"-code, if it returns nothing ... **Better design the `numba.jit(...)` test-payload a bit more carefully**, otherwise you again resort not to test anything reasonable to the O/P.

Comment: I was concerned with this initially, but since none of the functions have constant time scaling (none of them return) I assumed that numba jit did not, in fact, optimize the code away entirely. I may be wrong. I didn't want to conflate timings with returning, type conversions etc.